# PHP script processing/cpu time (Not wall clock time)

Tags: php, performance, time, php-7, processing-efficiency

I'm trying to profile some PHP scripts I'm running. I'm already measuring the wall clock time but now I want to know how much time the cpu has dedicated to the script.

Is there any way to measure cpu time of a script? I'm using php7.1

Comment: You should look into Xdebug for PHP for some advanced debugging and profiling: https://xdebug.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can use `xhprof` library to measure the cpu time. Here are guidelines of how you can use the library https://tideways.io/profiler/xhprof-for-php7-php5.6.